# Is the Hardy Littlewood maximal function non- integrable ？

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Some books said that the Hardy Littlewood maximal function of f, denoted by $$Hf(x)=sup_{r>0} \frac{1}{m(B(x,r))}\int_{B(x,r)} |f(y)| dy $$ is bounded by a function $C|x|^{-n}$when the norm of $x$ is very large, namely $\exists$ constants $C$ and $R$, st$Hf\geq C|x|^{-n}, \forall |x|\geq R$. How to prove this inequality? I have no idea. 
Then from this inequality, can we say that $Hf$ is non-integrable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this does say that $Hf$ is non-integrable, which is why for example $H$ is not bounded in $L^1$.

Now I'll try to explain the proof of the inequality.
Choose a radius $r_0$ such that $\int_{B(0,r_0)} |f(y)|\,dy = c > 0$ (this is possible so long as $f$ is not zero up to a set of measure zero).  Then for $|x| > r_0$ we know that 
$$
Hf(x) \ge \frac{1}{m(B(x,|x|+r_0)} \int_{B(x,|x|+r_0)} |f(y)|\,dy \gtrsim c (|x|+r_0)^{-n}
$$
because $B(0, r_0) \subset B(x, |x|+r_0)$.  Furthermore, when $|x|$ is much larger than $r_0$, $(|x|+r_0)^{-n} \gtrsim |x|^{-n}$.

Comment: Yes, and when f=0, a.e, we get Hf=0.