# Why can we not apply Markov's inequality to the Hardy-Littlewood Maximal function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f \in L_1(\mathbb{R}^d, \mu)$. Consider the discrete maximal function for fixed $r$:

$$M_rf(x) = \tfrac{1}{\mu(B_r(x))} \int_{B_r(x)} |f| dm$$

Clearly this is continuous and by Fubini's Theorem, $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f| dm = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}M_{r_n}f(x) dx$.

Why then is it that we cannot take a sequence $M_{r_n}f(x)$ monotonically approaching $\sup_{r > 0} M_rf(x)$, the Hardy-Littlewood function, and then, by the Monotone Convergence Theorem, conclude that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} Mf(x) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f|dm$$

I know this cannot be the case because it would seem to trivialize the Hardy-Littlewood inequality by Chebyshev's (or Markov's) inequality, but I cannot figure out what is the matter with this argument.

Comment: I believe it has to do with the fact that $Mf(x)$ is actually not integrable unless $f = 0$ a.e. See this thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838520/is-the-hardy-littlewood-maximal-function-non-integrable?rq=1

Comment: Would monotone convergence theorem not show integrability of the maximal function?

Comment: An idea as to what is going wrong: when you take the monotone limit of your sequence of functions in the final step, you assume that this sequence is monotone for every $x$. Surely there is a simple counter-example to this claim.